# websocket send slow for the firsttime

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket

First time, the `websocket.send` is slow. subsequent send's are faster.
I profiled the connections, and there is a `setTimeOut` before socket.send. 
That `setTimeOut` has no source. I am not sure whether it is related to chrome browser.

```
socket = new WebSocket(...);
socket.send(val)
```

any thoughts or help here?

Comment: initial connection is slower since there is more work involved ... websocket is a persistent connection protocol ...  subsequent traffic is quicker as it  avoids the chit chat of opening up the connection

Comment: is there a way to get that faster? like an empty message or something?